# help with minimal pairs in English

Tags: english, phonology, minimal-pairs

In a famous paper on phonology R. Jakobson made an example of an English minimal triplet as follows:

> *pop* ~ *tot* ~ *cock*

By this example he wanted to show that syllable onset and coda positions produce different realisations of the occlusives, but these realisations are just positional variants of the same phonemes.

I needed to present this example to my students but I realised that, while in Jakobson's times, when *cock* meant just a male chicken, and nothing else (at least, in **his** linguistic competence), this example sounded perfectly acceptable, today it would unavoidably provoke some giggles among the students.

I tried to change the vowels but different profanities came out again.

Could anyone help me with individuating a presentable, profanity free, minimal triplet in English? It must have the following structure:

/k/ Vowel /k/

/t/ Vowel /t/

/p/ Vowel /p/

My English competence apparently is not enough.

Comment: "Cock", meaning male chicken or make a gun ready to fire, is a perfectly good non-obscene English word.

Comment: @GregLee indeed it is. But I would like to prevent my students from even suspecting that there is something to laugh on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Vowels

- pap, tat, [<s>cack</s>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cack#Etymology_2) `/ɑ ~ æ/`
- pep, [teth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teth#English), [kek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kek#English) `/e ~ ɛ/` (Second word very rare, third very informal)
- peep, teat, [keek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keek#English) `/i/` (Is *teat* too anatomical for your taste?)
- pip, [<s>tit</s>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tit#Etymology_1), kick `/ɪ/`
- pup, tut, [<s>cuck</s>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cuck#Etymology_1) `/ʌ/`
- pop, tot, [<s>cock</s>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cock#Etymology_1) `/ɒ ~ ɔ/`
- [<s>poop</s>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poop#Etymology_2), toot, cook `/u ~ ʊ/`

#### Diphthongs

- pipe, tight, [<s>kike</s>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kike#English) `/aɪ/`
- [pape](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pape#English), [Tate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tate#English), cake `/eɪ/` (Second word a proper noun (name))
- pope, tote, coke `/oʊ ~ əʊ/` (Is [*coke* (cocaine)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coke#Etymology_2) problematic?)
- `?`, tout, [cowk](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cowk?s=ts) `/aʊ/` (Third word dialectal, Northeast Scot)
- `?`, `?`, `?` `/ɔɪ/`

How old are your students? I can't imagine that the momentary giggle that some of these words might raise would continue for very long or be detrimental to the lesson.

The only one I would avoid is `/aɪ/`, since therein lies a pretty offensive slur. Maybe avoid the ones which contain very uncommon words too, for the sake of familiarity to the audience. Everything else seems pretty benign, removed of context.

Comment: Thank you for this very exhausting answer. The students are never adult enough. On the other hand, this could be turned into a nice home assignment.

Comment: By the way, you can’t deny that the problematic words abound here

Comment: The non-existence of words like /paʊp/ and /kaʊk/ actually is part of a broader pattern of gaps in English phonotactics: the rimes /aʊp/ and /aʊk/ actually don't occur at all in English words (or if they do, very marginally). The diphthong /aʊ/ has a more restricted distribution than /aɪ/ in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Coke, pope, tote is the only one that completely avoids potential snicker-words.

Comment: 'coke' and 'tote' can connote drug use.